Providing an argument to the lambda / function passed to filter
In this code, the regular expression is hardcoded in filterf, which is then provided as the evaluating function to filter.
import re

filterf = lambda s:re.match(r'^T', s)
print("".join(list(filter(filterf, ["T x", "M y"])))) # outputs: T x

How would I recode it such that a regex literal can instead be provided to filterf as an argument? I'd like to use it like this:
import re

filterf = # ???
print("".join(list(filter(filterf(r'^T'), ["T x", "M y"])))) # outputs: T x


filterf = lambda pat: lambda s:re.match(pat,s)

As Michael Butscher says in their comment:
import re

filterf = lambda pat: lambda s: re.match(pat, s)
print("".join(list(filter(filterf(r"^T"), ["T x", "M y"]))))

This way filterf returns another function when called, and it is that second, dynamically created function that is passed to filter. Written out more clearly (it's not usually recommended to assign lambda functions to variables at all, let alone nested ones):
import re

def filterf(pattern):
    def inner(string):
        return re.match(pattern, string)
    return inner

print("".join(list(filter(filterf(r"^T"), ["T x", "M y"]))))

Although personally (and like many things, preferences vary), I don't find it very legible when too many parentheses stack up like that. Inner portions could be indented or assigned to intermediary values, but instead I'd probably write it like this, unpacking a list comprehension to pass as multiple arguments to print, and supplying "" as the sep argument:
import re

print(*[string for string in ["T x", "M y"] if re.match(r"^T", string)], sep="")

